# Wordpress migrated site - links and image url's not updating

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink

hope everyone is doing well.

I’m a newbee so please excuse me.

I’ve designed a website for a client, I’ve moved the site from local to live, hosting is through Godaddy:

http://www.tangledhairstudio.co.uk

I’ve run into a few issues, some of the links on the new website are not working, I’ve been sitting in-front of my laptop trying to fix them for more than a week and to no avail.

When I hover over the tabs/ buttons that are not working I can see the url is pointing towards the WordPress local (localhost:8888/tangledhairstudio/prices), surely what I want and what it should be is http://www.tangledhairstudio/prices ????

HALF WAY DOWN THE PAGE, IN THE SERVCE “SECTION”, 3 RED TABS NAMED: “SEE ALL”

I’ve used the WordPress plugins Search & Replace, Better Search Replace, Velvet Blue as well as using sql code to search and replace to edit parts of the url’s/links. This is the exact sql code I used below:

/** update URL in posts table **/
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, ‘http://localhost:8888/’,’http://www.’);

/** update URL in posts table **/
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, ‘http://localhost:8888/’, ‘http://www.’);

/** update URL in postmeta table **/
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,’http://localhost:8888/’,’http://www.’);

However, this worked by editing the url’s/ links in the database BUT, did nothing for the broken website links I was trying to change.

nothing seems to work whether i’ve used a plugin, snippet of code or hardcoded each and every field in the database.

ALSO, WHEN I VIEW THE WEBSITE ON MY MOBILE/ CELL, NONE OF THE IMAGES SHOW UP AND, SOME STUFF JUST SEEMS LITTLE OUT OF PLACE, I’M NOT SURE. ANY IDEAS?

please please please could I get some help and ideas how I can get this site running smoothly without any errors.

would much appreciate it,

many thanks

Leon

Comment: when you made the site on local what was the folder name

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of a WordPress site: Database and Files.

**The Database**

Your WordPress database contains every post, comment and link you have on your website/blog. So when you are developing your website on a local machine, then all links (for images, posts, pages) are in the form of http://localhost/ or http://localhost*:port*/.

When you move your website to an actual domain, the links in the database will need to be updated to match the new location (from *http://localhost* to *http://yourdomain.com*, for example). Which you can take care of as explained here on the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs). There are numerous plugins as well that make migrating a WordPress website real easy.

**Files**

Files that one needs to take care of are all in the /wp-content/ folder when migrating the website. As this folder contains all the media (images, documents etc) you upload to the media library, the plugins, and the theme files.

The problem you are facing: Try looking for hard coded links in your theme files (template files), your widgets, and for the sake of completeness, your CSS file(s) too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

run one more query in your live database
 and replace

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(meta_value,'http://localhost:8888/tangledhairstudio','http://www.tangledhairstudio.co.uk');
```

after that you you see the widget are gone, put the content widgwets from you local you live.

hope it will help you